# Print harmonic series for the given series in Python 3

Tags: python

I want to print harmonic series in python as follow but I don't understand how to do it, pls help and it would be nice if you could maybe explain how you did it. I have not tried any code and was not able to find it on the web

[image]

Comment: There is a distinct pattern to each element of the series. Look at the last one with `n` and try to think how you can translate that to a function with `n` as the argument. Then call this function in a loop. You say you tried something that didn't work. It would help if you actually posted it here so we can see how you went wrong and try to help you. But right now your question is off-topic. Please read about [ask] and how to provide a [mre]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### The problem

We want to iterate `n` (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ...) and pass it in the formula `nx/n!`, for example user ill define `x` by this line of code `x = int(input("What's the value of x? "))`, so image user types number 5, so we need to get: `1*5/1!`, `2*5/2!`, `3*5/3!`, `4*5/4!`.

Here is another problem: Python's `!` symbol means boolean invert, so !true is equal to false, not factorial.

#### factorial function in Python

So we need to define function factorial:

```py
def factorial(number):
  fact = 1
  
  for n in range(1, number+1): 
    fact *= n # The same as fact = fact * n

  return fact

# TEST OF THE FACTORIAL FUNCTION
# print(f'factorial(3) == 1*2*3 => { factorial(3) == 1*2*3 }')
```

#### Limit of the sequence

We actually need to get the `nlim` number from the user that tells the loop when to stop.

```py
nlim = int(input("What's the limit of the sequence? "))
```

#### The sequence

So, we need to get Python evaluate this (if `x` is equal to `5` and `n` is increasing from `1` by step `1` to limit `nlim`): `1*5/factorial(1)`, `2*5/factorial(2)`, `3*5/factorial(3)` and so on.

```py
results = [] # in this list all the results will be stored

for n in range(1, nlim+1):
  results.append((n*x) / factorial(n)) # here comes the formula!
```

#### Read sequence

```py
for i, result in enumerate(results):
  # enumerate([7, 8, 9]) will give us 2D list with indexes [[0, 7], [1, 8], [2, 9]]
  # Then we will iterate this, so on each loop cycle we get [0, 7], then [1, 8] and so on
  # if we do following: a, b = [1, 2] then variable a will be 1 and variable b will be 2

  print(f'result[{ i }]: { result }')
```

#### All the code

```py
def factorial(number):
  fact = 1
  
  for n in range(1, number+1): 
    fact *= n

  return fact

x = int(input("What's the value of x? "))
nlim = int(input("What's the limit of the sequence? "))

results = []

for n in range(1, nlim+1):
  results.append((n*x) / factorial(n))

for i, result in enumerate(results):
  print(f'result[{ i }]: { result }')
```

Comment: Can you please explain me what did you do, I am a beginner.

Comment: This does not give me the output in fraction

Comment: What's your Python version? Provide more information, write which function / line of code doesn't work please if possible.

Comment: My python version is 3.9.1 and I have not tried any code for it.

Comment: Then try this dev instructions / code to get to your needed result and provide feedback.

Comment: Yeah, I just had to print it in decimals so it worked, to print it like the picture it would be just putting x and and the number below it in a simple for loop and print the output.